# how to get value (int) in flutter from file .xlsx?

Tags: flutter, file, dart, xlsx, readfile

I have a simple code

```
Future<void> readExcelFile(String fileName) async {

  ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/$fileName");
  var bytes =
      data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
  var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);

  for (var table in excel.tables.keys) {

    for (var row in excel.tables[table].rows) {
     
      ........
      String a = row[0];
      String b = row[1];    <-------      error here

     .......
    }
  }
 }
```

row[1] -> return number but i want convert to string

this is error of me:

```
_TypeError (type 'NoSuchMethodError' is not a subtype of type 'String')
```

please hepl me

I try change "String" to int, var, dynamic but no work

Comment: you have the tables and the rows why are you trying to use row as rows?

Comment: you can help me edit ? please